# how can i make a loop using matlab?

Tags: matlab, regression

i have a regression model with 3 variables x1 x2 x3 and all possible regression models are 2^3=8 models.  x1 , x2 ,x3, x1x2, x1x3, x2x3 ,no variables and x1x2x3 i want to apply a method called AIC "Akaike's Information Criterion" to all subset models to choose the correct model , SO I wan to make a loop to apply aic on all subset models using matlab?
note: AIC = n log(s/n)+2k the correct model is the model with minimum aic
i know how to calculate aic but i don't know how to make the loop to apply aic to all subset models

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the various regression models? Are they all single parameter models? Or have you already created your 8 models? If so how are you storing them?

Comment: And you haven't defined what `n`, `s` and `k` represent. How do they relate to `x1`,`x2` and `x3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
AIC = zeros(2, 2, 2);
for i = 0:1
    for j = 0:1
        for k = 0:1
            state = [i;j;k];
            AIC(i+1, j+1, k+1) = %some computation based on state;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

"State" will include all combinations of parameters you specified, zeros meaning no parameter, ones meaning this parameter is included in computation. So state = [1 0 1] equals x1x3 case, [0 0 1] equals x3 case etc. 
Analogically, AIC(1, 1, 1) will have the result for case with empty set, AIC(1, 2, 1) for x2 case, AIC(2, 1, 2) for x1x3 case etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of `state`? You don't use it.

Comment: I'm not using it, because I don't know AIC method. "State" tells us, which variables of set x1, x2, and x3 should be used in current computation of AIC.
State will have the following values over the loops: 0,0,0; 0,0,1; 0,1,0; 0,1,1; 1,0,0; 1,0,1; 1,1,0; 1,1,1; Those correspond with: empty set, x3, x2, x2x3, x1, x1x3, x1x2 and finally x1x2x3.

I don't know the formulas for AIC, but I assume that author of the question knows how to call AIC method beeing given (in "state" variable) information which of x1, x2 and x3 should be used in this particular computation.

Comment: Also, I'm aware that "state" variable is unnecessary, as i, j and k contain all the information needed without being put into array. I added "state" only for the purpose of making the idea easier to understand.

Comment: Have you tried to vectorise it? I'm sure it must be possible.